# How to merge sorted sequences?

Tags: f#

Here’s a problem I’ve really been struggling with.  I need to merge two sorted sequences into a single sorted sequence.  Ideally, the algorithm should be lazy-evaluated, and not require caching more than one item from each sequence.  This is not a terribly difficult problem to solve, and I’ve been able to engineer a number of solutions in F#.  Unfortunately, every solution I’ve come up with has one of several problems.

1. Recursive calls to subsequence generators using yield!.  This produces elegant looking solutions, but the creation of a subsequence for every item is a performance killer.
2. Really arcane and unmaintainable code with deeply-stacked match switches, multiple nearly identical blocks of code, etc.
3. Code which forces F# into a purely procedural mode (lots of mutable values, etc.).

And all of the online examples I've been able to find founder on the same shoals.

Am I missing something obvious: like it's either really simple or else obviously impossible?  Does anyone know of a really elegant solution that is also efficient and mostly functional?  (It doesn’t have to be purely functional.)  If not, I may end up caching subsequences and using lists or arrays.

Comment: You might want to look at this for an example on algorithm and convert it to F#. http://code.activestate.com/recipes/141934-merging-sorted-sequences/

Comment: @James: the algorithm is not the problem, it's maintaining the laziness&order-complexity&elegance at once that's the issue.  The answer is `LazyList`.

Comment: @James: That ActiveState recipe site has some interesting stuff.

Comment: I am glad you found it interesting.  Some interesting ideas have been done in languages related to F#, to understand some concepts.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the LazyList type in the PowerPack.  I think I maybe even have this exact code lying around, let me look...

EDIT

not exactly it, but close: http://cs.hubfs.net/forums/thread/8136.aspx

Comment: Ok so I quickly through together this (http://pastebin.com/p5Va4z5p), it looks a little messy. Is there a good way to make it look as nice as non-lazy list code?

Comment: You don't need `as left` and `as right`, they're already called `a` and `b`.  It will never look "as nice", F# is eager, laziness takes a little work.  But I think this code looks quite nice, and I think @TechNeilogy will like it.

Comment: Helpful as always, and much appreciated, Brian :)

Comment: Thanks, Brian and Juliet; I think LazyList may be what I'm looking for.  I copied your examples for reference.  I'll have a go at working out a LazyList version on my own as an exercise, and then compare what I come up with.

Comment: `Seq` are generally significantly faster than lazy lists.

Answer (score 12):

> Ideally, the algorithm should be lazy-evaluate... the creation of a subsequence for every item is a performance killer

Lazy means slow but here is a solution using lazy lists:

```
let (++) = LazyList.consDelayed

let rec merge xs ys () =
  match xs, ys with
  | Cons(x, xs'), Cons(y, _) when x<y -> x ++ merge xs' ys
  | Cons(x, _), Cons(y, ys') -> y ++ merge xs ys'
  | Nil, xs | xs, Nil -> xs
```

I think by "lazy evaluated" you mean you want the merged result to be generated on demand so you can also use:

```
let rec merge xs ys = seq {
  match xs, ys with
  | x::xs, y::_ when x<y ->
      yield x
      yield! merge xs ys
  | x::_, y::ys ->
      yield y
      yield! merge xs ys
  | [], xs | xs, [] -> yield! xs
}
```

As you say, this is very inefficient. However, a `seq`-based solution doesn't have to be slow. Here, `Seq.unfold` is your friend and can make this over 4× faster by my measurements:

```
let merge xs ys =
  let rec gen = function
    | x::xs, (y::_ as ys) when x<y -> Some(x, (xs, ys))
    | xs, y::ys -> Some(y, (xs, ys))
    | [], x::xs | x::xs, [] -> Some(x, ([], xs))
    | [], [] | [], [] -> None
  Seq.unfold gen (xs, ys)
```

Answer (score 7):

Sequences don't really pattern match well.

Fortunately one of the advantages of F# *is* being able to drop down to imperative code when you need to, and I think it still idiomatic to use mutable state internally so long as the function is still pure to clients consuming the function. I think this style is really common in the F# source code wherever sequences are involved.

Its not pretty, but this works:

```
open System.Collections.Generic
let merge (a : #seq<'a>) (b : #seq<'a>) =
    seq {
        use a = a.GetEnumerator()
        use b = b.GetEnumerator()

        let aNext = ref <| a.MoveNext()
        let bNext = ref <| b.MoveNext()

        let inc (enumerator : IEnumerator<'a>) flag =       // '
            let temp = enumerator.Current
            flag := enumerator.MoveNext()
            temp
        let incA() = inc a aNext
        let incB() = inc b bNext

        while !aNext || !bNext do
            match !aNext, !bNext with
            | true, true ->
                if a.Current > b.Current then yield incB()
                elif a.Current < b.Current then yield incA()
                else yield incA(); yield incB()
            | true, false -> yield incA()
            | false, true -> yield incB()
            | false, false -> ()
    }
```

Comment: In general, my experience is that "if you call `GetEnumerator()`, then your code has a bug that you haven't found yet".

Comment: Thanks.  I think I'll try LazyList, but this is an interesting enough example to stash in my code archive.  On thing that struck me was the "inc" macro for reversing the "sense" of the enumeration.  This is a design pattern that seems to come up often, even in C#.

Comment: @Brian I've payed the price of `GetEnumerator` misuse.  I don't use sequences to represent data anymore except in my AI code where I want the sequences to change dynamically instead of for example recreating a list of events.  My general rule of thumb now is to only use `GetEnumerator` if I'm adding a function to `Seq`.