# Sequence vs LazyList

Tags: data-structures, f#, sequence, lazy-evaluation

I can't wrap my head around the differences between sequence and `LazyList`. They're both lazy and potentially infinite. While `seq<'T>` is `IEnumerable<'T>` from .NET framework, `LazyList` is included in [F# PowerPack](http://fsharppowerpack.codeplex.com/). In practice, I encounter sequences much more often than `LazyList`s.

*What are their differences in terms of performance, usage, readability, etc? What are reasons for such a bad reputation of `LazyList` compared to that of `seq`?*

Answer (score 31, accepted):

`LazyList` computes each element only once regardless of how many times the list is traversed. In this way, it's closer to a sequence returned from `Seq.cache` (rather than a typical sequence). But, other than caching, `LazyList` behaves exactly like a list: it uses a list structure under the hood and supports pattern matching. So you might say: use `LazyList` instead of `seq` when you need list semantics and caching (in addition to laziness).

Regarding both being infinite, `seq`'s memory usage is constant while `LazyList`'s is linear.

These [docs](http://fsprojects.github.io/FSharpx.Collections/reference/fsharpx-collections-lazylist-1.html) may be worth a read.

Comment: +1, cool, I didn't know about caching part. Could you give an example which requires both laziness and list semantics?

Comment: Traversing a sequence while simultaneously accessing multiple elements can be done with a `seq`, but it's much cleaner using `LazyList` + pattern matching.

Comment: See e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3484315/how-to-merge-sorted-sequences-in-f and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1306140/f-why-is-using-a-sequence-so-much-slower-than-using-a-list-in-this-example/1306267#1306267

Comment: @pad: I added a link to the old docs on MSR. It explains them pretty well.

Comment: How does caching referred here compare to memoization which in Haskell world means once a value is computed, it is saved and used again if needed in the future?

Answer (score 19):

In addition to Daniel's answer, I think the main practical difference is how you process the `LazyList` or `seq` structures (or computations).

- If you want to process `LazyList`, you would typically write a recursive function using pattern matching (quite similar to processing of normal F# lists)
- If you want to process `seq`, you can either use built-in functions or you have to write imperative code that calls `GetEnumerator` and then uses the returned enumerator in a loop (which may be written as a recursive function, but it will mutate the enumerator). You cannot use the usual head/tail style (using `Seq.tail` and `Seq.head`), because that is extremely inefficient - because `seq` does not keep the evaluated elements and the result of `Seq.head` needs to re-iterate from the start.

Regarding the reputation of `seq` and `LazyList`, I think that F# library design takes a pragmatic approach - since `seq` is actually .NET `IEnumerable`, it is quite convenient for .NET programming (and it is also nice because you can treat other collections as `seq`). Lazy lists are not as frequent and so normal F# list and `seq` are sufficient in most of the scenarios.