# Performance of seq<int> vs Lazy<LazyList<int>> in F#

Tags: f#, infinite, seq, hamming-numbers

There is a well known solution for generating an infinite stream of Hamming numbers (i.e. all positive integers `n` where `n = 2^i * 3^j * 5^k`).  I have implemented this in two different ways in F#.  The first method uses `seq<int>`.  The solution is elegant, but the performance is terrible.  The second method uses a custom type where the tail is wrapped in `Lazy<LazyList<int>>`.  The solution is clunky, but the performance is amazing.

Can someone explain why the performance using `seq<int>` is so bad and if there is a way to fix it?  Thanks.

Method 1 using `seq<int>`.

```
// 2-way merge with deduplication
let rec (-|-) (xs: seq<int>) (ys: seq<int>) =
    let x = Seq.head xs
    let y = Seq.head ys
    let xstl = Seq.skip 1 xs
    let ystl = Seq.skip 1 ys
    if x < y then seq { yield x; yield! xstl -|- ys }
    elif x > y then seq { yield y; yield! xs -|- ystl }
    else seq { yield x; yield! xstl -|- ystl }

let rec hamming: seq<int> = seq {
    yield 1
    let xs = Seq.map ((*) 2) hamming
    let ys = Seq.map ((*) 3) hamming
    let zs = Seq.map ((*) 5) hamming
    yield! xs -|- ys -|- zs
}

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 
    Seq.iter (printf "%d, ") <| Seq.take 100 hamming
    0
```

Method 2 using `Lazy<LazyList<int>>`.

```
type LazyList<'a> = Cons of 'a * Lazy<LazyList<'a>>

// Map `f` over an infinite lazy list
let rec inf_map f (Cons(x, g)) = Cons(f x, lazy(inf_map f (g.Force())))

// 2-way merge with deduplication
let rec (-|-) (Cons(x, f) as xs) (Cons(y, g) as ys) =
    if x < y then Cons(x, lazy(f.Force() -|- ys))
    elif x > y then Cons(y, lazy(xs -|- g.Force()))
    else Cons(x, lazy(f.Force() -|- g.Force()))

let rec hamming =
    Cons(1, lazy(let xs = inf_map ((*) 2) hamming
                 let ys = inf_map ((*) 3) hamming
                 let zs = inf_map ((*) 5) hamming
                 xs -|- ys -|- zs))

[<EntryPoint>]
let main args =
    let a = ref hamming
    let i = ref 0
    while !i < 100 do
        match !a with
        | Cons (x, f) ->
            printf "%d, " x
            a := f.Force()
            i := !i + 1
    0
```

Answer (score 8):

Ganesh is right in that you're evaluating the sequence multiple times. `Seq.cache` will help improve performance, but you get much better performance out of `LazyList` because the underlying sequence is only ever evaluated once then cached, so it can be traversed much more rapidly. In fact, this is a good example of where `LazyList` *should* be used over a normal `seq`.

It also looks like there is some significant overhead introduced by your use of `Seq.map` here. I believe the compiler is allocating a closure each time it's called there. I changed your `seq` based code to use `seq`-expressions there instead, and it's about 1/3 faster than the original for the first 40 numbers in the sequence:

```
let rec hamming: seq<int> = seq {
    yield 1
    let xs = seq { for x in hamming do yield x * 2 }
    let ys = seq { for x in hamming do yield x * 3 }
    let zs = seq { for x in hamming do yield x * 5 }
    yield! xs -|- ys -|- zs
}
```

My [ExtCore](https://github.com/jack-pappas/ExtCore) library includes a `lazyList` computation builder which works just like `seq`, so you can simplify your code like this:

```
// 2-way merge with deduplication
let rec (-|-) (xs: LazyList<'T>) (ys: LazyList<'T>) =
    let x = LazyList.head xs
    let y = LazyList.head ys
    let xstl = LazyList.skip 1 xs
    let ystl = LazyList.skip 1 ys
    if x < y then lazyList { yield x; yield! xstl -|- ys }
    elif x > y then lazyList { yield y; yield! xs -|- ystl }
    else lazyList { yield x; yield! xstl -|- ystl }

let rec hamming : LazyList<uint64> = lazyList {
    yield 1UL
    let xs = LazyList.map ((*) 2UL) hamming
    let ys = LazyList.map ((*) 3UL) hamming
    let zs = LazyList.map ((*) 5UL) hamming
    yield! xs -|- ys -|- zs
}

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =
    let watch = Stopwatch.StartNew ()

    hamming
    |> LazyList.take 2000
    |> LazyList.iter (printf "%d, ")

    watch.Stop ()
    printfn ""
    printfn "Elapsed time: %.4fms" watch.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds

    System.Console.ReadKey () |> ignore
    0   // Return an integer exit code
```

(NOTE: I also made your `(-|-)` function generic, and modified `hamming` to use 64-bit unsigned ints because 32-bit signed ints overflow after a bit). This code runs through the first 2000 elements of the sequence on my machine in ~450ms; the first 10000 elements takes ~3500ms.

Comment: I'm surprised that a `seq`-comprehension is so much faster than `Seq.map`.   I also tried to get this to work with F# PowerPack, but I haven't been successful so far.

Comment: @fysx Use my ExtCore library - it contains an updated (and maintained) version of the `LazyList` code from the F# PowerPack. It also has a `lazyList` builder which greatly simplifies writing this kind of code.

Comment: @fysx The `seq`-comprehension is usually faster because it can be better optimized by the compiler. `Seq.map` isn't inherently slow, but in this case there's a lot of overhead because the code is repeatedly evaluating the sequence, and the compiled code has to allocate a closure each time `Seq.map` is called.

Comment: I used the Package Manager Console and 'Install-Package ExtCore'.  Without `main`, but only `(-|-)` and `hamming`, I get "This expression was expected to have type `LazyList<'a>` but here has type `LazyList<uint64>`" for `hamming`. I'm using Visual Studio 2013.  I tried specifying the types, but generally there's some type mismatch between `lazyList` and `hamming`.  Sad.

Comment: @fysx That's odd -- I have no problem compiling the code above, even if I comment out `main`. Would you mind opening an issue on the ExtCore github page about this? I'd like to help you solve the problem and it'd be easy to move the discussion there.

Comment: My bad.  I had both FSharp.PowerPack and ExtCore as references.  Removing FSharp.PowerPack made it work.

Comment: LazyList is containined in ExtCore, a Nuget package for FSharp:

https://github.com/jack-pappas/ExtCore

Answer (score 3):

Your `seq` for `hamming` is re-evaluated from the beginning on each recursive call. [`Seq.cache`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee370430.aspx) is some help:

```
let rec hamming: seq<int> =
    seq {
        yield 1
        let xs = Seq.map ((*) 2) hamming
        let ys = Seq.map ((*) 3) hamming
        let zs = Seq.map ((*) 5) hamming
        yield! xs -|- ys -|- zs
    } |> Seq.cache
```

However as you point out the `LazyList` is still much better on large inputs, even if every single sequence is cached.

I'm not entirely certain why they differ by more than a small constant factor, but perhaps it's better to just focus on making the `LazyList` less ugly. Writing something to convert it to a `seq` makes processing it much nicer:

```
module LazyList =
    let rec toSeq l =
        match l with
        | Cons (x, xs) ->
            seq {
                yield x
                yield! toSeq xs.Value
            }
```

You can then use your simple `main` directly. It's also not really necessary to use mutation to process the `LazyList`, you could just do so recursively.

The definition doesn't look so bad though the `lazy` and `Force()` do clutter it up a bit. That looks marginally better if you use `.Value` instead of `.Force()`. You could also define a [computation builder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233182.aspx) for `LazyList` similar to the `seq` one to recover the really nice syntax, though I'm not sure it's worth the effort.

Comment: Sprinkling `|> Seq.cache` throughout after I use `seq {...}` does improve performance, but not substantially (especially if I compute much larger numbers in the sequence.  I noticed http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9201402/sequence-vs-lazylist, which seems to compliment your suggestion well.

Comment: For 1..100 it made it near-instantaneous compared to very slow. What's a typical number where your lazy lists still outperform it substantially?

Comment: OK, I see it doesn't really work well for 1000 and 10000 is a dead loss even if I put `Seq.cache` on every single sequence.

Comment: Try 1500.   The `LazyList` version should be noticeably faster.

Comment: [ExtCore](https://github.com/jack-pappas/ExtCore) includes a `lazyList` computation builder, so you need not build your own :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sequence base version with better performance.

```
let hamming =
    let rec loop nextHs =
        seq {
            let h = nextHs |> Set.minElement
            yield h
            yield! nextHs 
                |> Set.remove h 
                |> Set.add (h*2) |> Set.add (h*3) |> Set.add (h*5) 
                |> loop
            }

    Set.empty<int> |> Set.add 1 |> loop
```