# F# sequence operations majorly slow compared to List?

Tags: list, f#, sequence

Used F# List and Seq to merge two sorted lists/sequences. The values are obtained by reading in two files from secondary memory - the results of the file reads are stored in two sequences. Assuming integers are stored for testing purposes, now trying to merge these to print out a sorted series using this code:

```
let rec printSortedSeq l1 l2 = 
    match ( l1, l2) with
    | l1,l2 when Seq.isEmpty l1 && Seq.isEmpty l2 -> printfn "";
    | l1, l2 when Seq.isEmpty l1 -> printf "%d " (Seq.head l2);  printSortedSeq l1 (Seq.skip 1 l2);
    | l1, l2 when Seq.isEmpty l2-> printf "%d " (Seq.head l1);  printSortedSeq (Seq.skip 1 l1) [];

    | l1,l2 -> if Seq.head l1 = Seq.head l2 then printf "%d " (Seq.head l1);  printSortedSeq (Seq.skip 1 l1) (Seq.skip 1 l2); 
                               elif Seq.head l1 < Seq.head l2 then printf "%d " (Seq.head l1);  printSortedSeq (Seq.skip 1 l1) (Seq.skip 1 l2); 
                               else printf "%d " (Seq.head l2);  printSortedSeq (Seq.skip 1 l1) (Seq.skip 1 l2);
```

The code was originally written to merge two sorted lists:

```
let rec printSortedList l1 l2 = 
    match ( l1, l2) with
    | h1 :: t1 , h2 :: t2 -> if h1 = h2 then printf "%d " h1;  printSortedList t1 t2; 
                               elif h1 < h2 then printf "%d " h1;  printSortedList t1 l2; 
                               else printf "%d " h2;  printSortedList l1 t2;
    | [] , h2 :: t2 ->  printf "%d " h2;  printSortedList [] t2;
    | h1 :: t1, [] -> printf "%d " h1;  printSortedList t1 [];
    | [], [] -> printfn"";
```

The performance of using them compared hugely in favor of Lists. I'm giving the timing results after doing #time;; in the FSI on some trial inputs.

```
let x = [0..2..500];
let y = [1..2..100];

let a = {0..2..500}
let b = {1..2..100}
```

printSortedList x y;;
Real: 00:00:00.012, CPU: 00:00:00.015

printSortedSeq a b;;
Real: 00:00:00.504, CPU: 00:00:00.515

The question is - is there any way to make things faster using sequences? Because though lists are much faster, since the files that will provide the input are very large ( > 2 GB) they won't fit in main memory and so I am reading in the values from file as a lazy sequence. Converting those to lists before merging kinda defeats the whole purpose.

Comment: How are you measuring the time? It looks like you are timing the printing code too and that will naturally be slow.

Comment: With both sequences (see my answer below) and lazy lists merging should run in `O(1)` memory and `O(N1+N2)` time. At that point there is just a constant factor difference - before optimizing every bit of it, try the simplest solution on your input and see if it is good enough.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seq.skip is an anti-pattern.  Use LazyList from the F# PowerPack, or use enumerators (GetEnumerator...MoveNext...Current) to efficiently traverse a Seq.  See other similar Q&A.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3484315/how-to-merge-sorted-sequences for reference.

Comment: Thanks a lot Brian and pad for that SO link. using LazyList now. Enumerator needed mutable values (at least the way I wrote it) - so LasyList it is. Timing info coming soon.

Answer (score 4):

As toyvo mentioned, this can be greatly simplified using a stateful enumerator:

```
let mkStatefulEnum (e: IEnumerator<'T>) =
  let x = ref None
  fun move ->
    if move then x := (if e.MoveNext() then Some e.Current else None)
    !x

let merge (a: seq<'T>) (b: seq<'T>) =
  seq {
    use x = a.GetEnumerator()
    use y = b.GetEnumerator()
    let nextX = mkStatefulEnum x
    let nextY = mkStatefulEnum y
    yield! Seq.unfold (fun (a, b) ->
      match a, b with
      | Some a, Some b -> 
        if a < b then Some (a, (nextX true, nextY false))
        else Some (b, (nextX false, nextY true))
      | Some a, None -> Some (a, (nextX true, nextY false))
      | None, Some b -> Some (b, (nextX false, nextY true))
      | None, None -> None
    ) (nextX true, nextY true)
  }
```

Comment: This works great, but using `seq {}` in conjunction with a single `yield!` is useless, so both can be safely removed.

Answer (score 3):

The answer to your question, are F# sequence operations majorly slow compared to List, is no. Your sequence code runs in polynomial time due to sequence re-traversal, while your list code runs in linear time.

For the record, it is possible to merge two sorted sequences in linear time. For example:

```
open System.Collections.Generic

type State<'T> =
    | Neutral
    | Left of 'T
    | Right of 'T
    | Tail

let mergeSeqs (a: seq<'T>) (b: seq<'T>) =
    let cmp x y =
        match compare x y with
        | 1 -> Some (y, Left x)
        | _ -> Some (x, Right y)
    seq {
        use x = a.GetEnumerator()
        use y = b.GetEnumerator()
        let step st =
            match st with
            | Neutral ->
                match x.MoveNext(), y.MoveNext() with
                | true, true -> cmp x.Current y.Current
                | true, false -> Some (x.Current, Tail)
                | false, true -> Some (y.Current, Tail)
                | false, false -> None
            | Left v ->
                match y.MoveNext() with
                | true -> cmp v y.Current
                | false -> Some (v, Neutral)
            | Right v ->
                match x.MoveNext() with
                | true -> cmp x.Current v
                | false -> Some (v, Neutral)
            | Tail ->
                match x.MoveNext(), y.MoveNext() with
                | false, false -> None
                | true, _ -> Some (x.Current, Tail)
                | _, true -> Some (y.Current, Tail)
        yield! Seq.unfold step Neutral
    }
```

You can improve on that by reducing consing. Design a custom IEnumerator with mutable state similar to `State<'T>`, and use that as the basis for the merged sequence.

Comment: could you please explain a bit more about what Left, Right and Tail are signifying in the pattern matching?

Comment: @AruniRC, `State` datatype classifies the state of the merged iterator, Left/Right/Tail/Neutral are cases. There are several ways to do it, you do not have to follow my code.