# Error in pattern matching with LazyList in F#

Tags: f#, pattern-matching, lazy-evaluation

Trying to merge two LazyLists in F# after [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11201850/297353) question on SO. Originally wrote for matching two Lists. Modified that to get this:

```
let rec printLazyList (l1:LazyList<int>) (l2:LazyList<int>) =
    match (l1, l2) with
        | t, s when t |> LazyList.isEmpty && s |> LazyList.isEmpty -> printfn "";
        | t , LazyList.Cons(h2,t2) when t |> LazyList.isEmpty -> printf "%d " h2 
                                                                 let a = LazyList.empty 
                                                                 printLazyList a t2
        | LazyList.Cons(h1,t1), s when s |> LazyList.isEmpty -> printf "%d " h1 
                                                                let b = LazyList.empty 
                                                                printLazyList t1 b
        | LazyList.Cons(h1,t1), LazyList.Cons(h2,t2) -> if h1 = h2 then 
                                                            printf "%d " h1 
                                                            printLazyList t1 t2 
                                                        elif h1 < h2 then 
                                                            printf "%d " h1  
                                                            printLazyList t1 l2
                                                        else 
                                                            printf "%d " h2  
                                                            printLazyList l1 t2
```

The problem is it is giving no output. None of the conditions are being satisfied (checked this by putting a `|_,_ printfn "nothing matches"` at the end of the pattern matching. Is there a fundamental difference in the `cons` that is used in LazyList versus the `::` in the usual F# lists? Because this worked for normal lists (cf. the link above).

Sorry if this is again a really n00b question. FP is looking rather difficult at this point.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you test the function using `fsi`, be careful since there is a lot of noise in `fsi` console and your eyes may skip the line of output.

Here is a complete test (I did some cleanups by using `Nil` instead of `isEmpty` and reorganizing pattern matching for readability):

```
#r "FSharp.PowerPack.dll"

open LazyList

let rec printLazyList l1 l2 =
    match l1, l2 with
    | Nil, Nil -> printfn ""
    | Nil, Cons(h2, t2) -> 
        printf "%d " h2 
        printLazyList LazyList.empty t2
    | Cons(h1, t1), Nil -> 
        printf "%d " h1 
        printLazyList t1 LazyList.empty
    | Cons(h1, t1), Cons(h2, t2) when h1 = h2 ->
        printf "%d " h1 
        printLazyList t1 t2 
    | Cons(h1, t1), Cons(h2, t2) when h1 < h2 ->
        printf "%d " h1  
        printLazyList t1 l2
    | Cons(h1, t1), Cons(h2, t2) ->
        printf "%d " h2  
        printLazyList l1 t2

let x = LazyList.ofList [1; 2];;
let y = LazyList.ofList [3; 4];;
printLazyList x y;;
```

Comment: <facepalm> darn. thanks for mainly the clean-up, goodness knows how i missed it in the lab!